# Which is better to use - PhantomJS or just browser's Print function?

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I am writing a reporting app wherein I need the output in PDF format. I am planning to generate a webpage and call PhantomJS on that webpage to get the PDF. However, for this to work users will have to install PhantomJS (+ NodeJs) libraries as well.

Why don't I just ask them to print the webpage as PDF? They both (PhantomJS and Browser's Print function) shall produce the same output, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes chrome browser should print to PDF fine and better than phantomjs is some cases.

But you can use phantomJS in the server to generate the PDF, so user doesn't need phantomJS installed on his machine, and could be used from Firefox,IE,Safari,Mobile, etc..

So it is back to your environment and your requirements